# Do you lose precision when converting from real to money datatype in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, types

I have a table with datafields in real datatype. Do you lose precision when converting to money or decimal datatype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the precision and scale that you have specified for the decimal type. If you for example have a `decimal(19,2)` and try to convert the `real` number `1.123`, you will get the value `1.12`.

The `decimal` type has higher precision than the `real` type, so it's capable of handling any `real` value that is within it's range without loosing precision.

The `money` type can hold the same data as a decimal(19,4).

The `decimal` and `money` types are exact types, while `real` is an approximate type. If you convert a `real` to a `decimal` you may see a value that is not exactly what you see in the `real` value, but that is because the `real` value is rounded when it's displayed and the `decimal` value is not.

Answer (score 2):

Float(4) (aka real) and float(8) are IEEE 754 floating point types. **It is a mistake to use them to represent monetary values**. They are meant for calculations in which the values have a large dynamic range while being stored in a relatively small number of bytes. The use of floating point numbers and how precise and accurate they are is a science in itself and not easily explained.